# Where can I find all blocks/elements related to Newsletters in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I need to disable or hide all elements/blocks related to Newsletter.
As of the moment, I knew only 2 places on where these things exist:

- Footer (subscribe by entering your email address)
- Create Account Page (sign up for newsletter checkbox)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide newsletter in `default.xml` of your active theme

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

check at : `vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` if magento is installed `using composer`

Comment: That won't remove the subscribe to newsletter checkbox in the registration screen.

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed this with my fellow developer that the ff. sections are the locations of the blocks/elements related to Newsletter:

•Footer (subscribe by entering your email address)
•Create Account Page (sign up for newsletter checkbox)
•Account Dashboard